# What is an antonym for the term "straight-A student?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that implies stupidity in the context of academics in the same way the term "straight-A student" implies intelligence.

Comment: [***Dunce***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dunce) is particularly associated with lack of *academic* ability (***duffer*** may also suit).

Comment: Perhaps you want **Someone who misuses *infer* to mean *imply***. :(

Comment: My bad, and guilty as charged. Editing now. =)

Comment: Although not a perfect fit to the question as phrased, and not *necessarily* implying lack of academic ability, [dropout](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dropout) may be what you're after.

Comment: Yes the closest I can think of is @FumbleFingers's dunce, but for some reason I have a connotation that dunce applies to normal life as well, e.g., a dunce is just not a very bright person in general. I don't like dropout either because this is often used to refer to lazy/busy students, who may be smart enough to complete their degrees, but choose not to out of laziness or other reasons. E.g., Bill Gates was a `dropout` but I wouldn't say he has a lack of academic intelligence.

Comment: The opposite of an _A-student_ would be an _F-student_, I suppose. The phrase isn't common because we don't tend to talk about them as much.

Comment: There's also _failure_, although this needs context, since people can fail in many ways.

Comment: @Tommy, good analysis. I'm not sure if there is a word that fits the bill perfectly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I ended up using dunce. If you'll make it into an answer (perhaps including an analysis of how it does and doesn't fit the requirements), I will accept it.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly. So presumably a _gay-F student_ would be a good opposite to a _straight-A student_ …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dunce) has the definition...

> ***dunce*** *- someone who is stupid or slow at learning things*
>    *People with the learning disability dyslexia were once simply dismissed as **dunces***.

The etymology, with focus on the specific term ***dunce cap*** as used in a schoolroom/academic context, is more fully covered by [this Wikipedia article](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dunce).

For a more "modern" term (often used facetiously), there's always [***academically challenged***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22academically%20challenged%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: In case it helps, if they are no longer in school and did not graduate, you can say "drop-out."

Answer (score 1):

An opposite would be a *failing*  or *flunking* student.